# Compare two text fields, iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextfield

1. I have two text fields in one view.
2. I saved one text field in `NSSUserDefaults` and load in `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

I try to compare those two text fields, with a button:

```
if ([st1 isEqualToString: st2])
{
    // do something 
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

When I run this on my iPhone for test, and I press the button, he give me the }else} do something before I write something.

I wanted check first those two text field isEqualToString when I press the button before write something. and before save something, and after save do

```
if ([st1 isEqualToString: st2])
{
    // do something 
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and make it clearer exactly what you want to do? The first half is fine, just the second half is a bit confusing.

Comment: i agree with @adamjansch - I think your trying to say, can I check that the fields are matching before you save defaults?  Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if([textField1.text isEqualToString:textField2.text])
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks... is working good , perfect , but only if I leave in blank. When I save the textField2 in -(void)viewDidLoad is no work any more only work else{ do something }

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with:

```
if([str1.text isEqualToString:str2.text])
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```